# how to consume json in angular js ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how would i do ng-repeat with  restful service and value not show in view. using angular js.

```
 $http({
        url: "http://.....net/veranstaltungskalender/webservice.php?action=get_description_byId&id=" + $stateParams.id,
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function (res) {
        $scope.descripition = res.data.data;
        $ionicLoading.hide();

    }, function (err) {
        console.error('ERR', err);

    });
```

and my html is..

```
                       <div class="row header">
                        <div class="col">Pos</div>
                        <div class="col">Activity</div>
                        <div class="col">Who</div>
                        <div class="col">Notes</div>
                        <div class="col">Time</div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="row" ng-repeat="data in descripition">
                        <li> {{data.Pos}}</li>
                        <li class="col">{{data.Activity}}</li>
                        <li class="col">{{data.Who}}</li>
                        <li class="col">{{data.Notes}}</li>
                        <li class="col">{{data.Time}}</li>

                    </ul>
```

Comment: is your $scope.description is an array ?

Comment: And what is the error? Btw: never create an url this way, use resources

Comment: Can you share output of console.dir($scope.descripition) ? Syntax looks okay.

Comment: why don't u use ng-hide when the data is there in  $scope.description??

Comment: attach a plunker ?

Comment: first time work on angular dont have any idea about ng-hide. i need data fil  my view

Comment: i think there is some problem in the response that you have provided.kindly recheck. the syntax is right

Comment: the response that you have provided is an object not an array...kindly recheck

Comment: json resp is object,

Comment: check code snippet http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzkAPW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, Your $scope.description is not an array but an object of arrays. ng-repeat looks for array.

> An Array is like this : [ {},{},..]
>
> An Object is like this : { "prop1" : [..],..}

Check out snippet how should be the structure of same : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXgvxR

```
    $scope.description =  [{

        "Pos": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8"],
        "Time": ["Bis 7", "8.00 8.50", "8.509.00", "9.00 11.00", "11.00 11.10", "11.10 13", "13.00"]
    },
                                                 {
                "Pos": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8"],
        "Time": ["Bis 7", "8.00 8.50", "8.509.00", "9.00 11.00", "11.00 11.10", "11.10 13", "13.00"]    
                                                 }
    ]
}
```

> If you are looking for just a work around, put `$scope.description = [
>   $scope.description ]`; after `$scope.description = res.data.data`;

Comment: I understood your code, What i meant , whatever description you get from server is not an array. Either make that an array while sending from server or adapt in you angular code.

Comment: If you are looking for just a work around, put $scope.description = [ $scope.description ]; after  $scope.description = res.data.data; .

Comment: please give me example

Comment: could you paste here the data you receive from the server?

Comment: :( . Just put $scope.description = [ $scope.description ]; after $scope.description = res.data.data , It will work.

Comment: Also please accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: i put it on. Array [0] is undefined

Comment: You are getting null from server it seems. It is not an syntax problem. Print res.data.data in console and check.

Comment: when i Print res.data.data on console error appear Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Don't work on codepen. In your desktop , what is error. Codepen does not allow request and all.  Try on your machine, take screen shot of error and post a new question. We have come too off-topic now.

Comment: Wo isliye ki jo data aa raha hain, wo us format mein nahi hain, jo ng-repeat expect kar raha hain. Just for testing, hard code $scope.description to array What i have given in answer. Then share the output.